# Why do I don't get logical result to my GroupBy to filter for duplicates?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Database Table with 5 Columns. When I want to filter them for duplicates I use `GroupBy()` in combination with a `Where(x => x.Count > 1)`. For the `GroupBy()` I use all the Table Columns except the `Id`. The Problem is, when I use 4 of the 5 to `GroupBy()`  I get around 60 duplicates. But when I `GroupBy()` all 5 (of course without the Id) I get around 80 duplicates. Do I missunderstood `GroupBy()` ?

```
var AmountOfDuplicates = db.TestTable
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Type, x.CategoryId, x.Number, /*x.Form*/})
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Count();
```

I expected that with the growing amount of GroupElements, that the result of duplicates must be same or lower.

Comment: Well your expectation is wrong. Is there actually a problem with the output? Please [edit], and show an example of `db.TestTable`, the output of your current code, and the output you expect.

Comment: You may want to start with inline example like `(new[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}).GroupBy(x=> new{ a =x %2}).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Count()` vs. `(new[]{1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10}).GroupBy(x=> new{a = x %2, b = x%3}).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Count()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the table:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
|----------|----------|
| A        | 1        |
| A        | 1        |
| A        | 2        |
| A        | 2        |
| A        | 3        |
| B        | 1        |
| B        | 1        |
| B        | 2        |
| B        | 2        |
| B        | 3        |
```

If you only grouped by column 1, there would be two groups, and both groups contain 5 elements, so they both satisfy the `.Where(x => x.Count() > 1)` condition. The final `Count()` would return 2, because 2 groups have more than 1 element in them.

If you grouped by both column1 and column2, there would be 6 groups (A,1), (A,2), (B,1), (B,2), (A, 3) and (B, 3). The first 4 all have 2 elements each, and the last two both have 1 element only. The final `Count()` would return 4, because 4 groups have more than 1 element in them.

You probably didn't mean to count how many *groups* of duplicates there are, but how many *rows* are duplicated. For example, when grouping by column 1 only, the number of duplicate rows is 10 - every row is duplicated. When grouping by both column 1 and column 2, the number of duplicate rows is 8, because (A,3) and (B,3) are unique.

If that is indeed what you mean, you should add up the counts in each group, after removing the unique rows. You can `Select` each group's count first,

```
var duplicateRowsCount = table
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select(group => group.Count())
    .Where(c => c > 1) // remove unique rows
    .Sum()
```

Comment: Or `.GroupBy(...).Where(group => group.Count() > 1).Sum(group => group.Count())`

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, but I didn’t like writing `Count()` twice. :)